# Can I use ethernet for point to point communication utilizing broadcast?

Tags: ethernet

Hypothetically if I wanted to make a custom point to point protocol that uses Ethernet, can I use Ethernet in such a way where the two devices communicate with each other by broadcasting their messages? I know that in practice you would always use IP addresses and ports but the question is purely academic.

Comment: Possible, yes. Reasonable, no. Broadcasting is inefficient and Ethernet is rather hard to tap into for an application-layer protocol on most current platforms. You'd be *much* better off using decent IP addressing and UDP in the transport layer.

Comment: Perhaps if you describe in a little more detail what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to suggest a better way,.

Comment: @RonTrunk I've seen many devices like PLCs using Ethernet for a point to point connection. You don't need to set up an IP address. You plug in the cable and you are good to go. I was wondering how did this solution approach the fact that it does not know the endpont's IP address. I reasoned that one approach would be using custom layer 2 protocol for IP identification and the other would be using broadcast. I just wanted to know if the latter was even possible, however as Zac67 mentioned it wouldn't be practical.

Comment: Ethernet uses a different address scheme (MAC addresses). It has nothing to do with IP addresses. On a single network , you don’t need IP.

Comment: In other words, PLCs use MAC addresses, not IP addresses.

Comment: @Ron Trunk You are right! I assumed that PC software didn't bother to go as low as layer 2 but I was wrong I guess. I still have the same question though, just exchange "IP address" with MAC address. How would one find out which MAC address does the other endpoint have? Would I need to have an ARP like layer 2 protocol that discovers the other device's MAC address or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You could use a custom discovery protocol to exchange addresss information but most likely these days you would just fallback to RFC 3927 addresses.

Comment: For examples of layer 2 protocols, see NETBIOS and NETBEUI.

Comment: You can make an ARP-like protocol but on upper, application layer which will build a distributed mapping of MAC to PLCs id.